# How to get Value from popup to parent

Tags: jquery, mysql, codeigniter

Hello Every body how to send data values from popup to parent ?!

I have a an element like this:

```
<input type="text" name="id_name_project" value="" id="id_name_project" size="60" >
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>itemin/select_data_name_project" class="select">SELECT</a>
```

This is my popup:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".select").colorbox({rel:'group', iframe:true, width:"900", height:"450"});
});
```

The button:

```
<a href="" class="name_project" value="<?php echo $db['id_name_project']; ?>" val_name_project="<?php echo $db['name_project']; ?>">ADD</a>
```

My question is how do I send `value="<?php echo $db['id_name_project']; ?>"` and `val_name_project="<?php echo $db['name_project']; ?>"`  from a href popup to value element `id="id_name_project"` (parent)?

Answer (score 1):

Add an ID or class or something to identify your ADD button, then you can do something like this:

```
<a id="addbutton" value="<?php echo $db['id_name_project']; ?>" val_name_project="<?php echo $db['name_project']; ?>">Add</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#addbutton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var buttonvalue = $(this).attr('value');
    var val_name_project = $(this).attr('val_name_project');

    $('input[name="id_name_project"]').val(buttonvalue);
    // do something similar with val_name_project if you want to
});
```